# How to make link in bootstrap tooltip

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I used Visual Studio 2013 and make Web Project (in C# MVC5). I add bootstrap tolltip

```
$("a").tooltip({    
    animated: 'fade',
    placement: 'right',
    html: true,
    delay: { show: 750, hide: 100 },
});
});
```

And title code

```
<td style="width:200px;">
<a href="@Url.Action("Szczegoly", new { id = item.TowarId })"
data-toggle="tooltip"
title="
  <div style='position:relative'>
  <img src='@item.FotoUrl' class='imgTooltip' />
  <span style=' position:absolute; top:0; font-size:25px;'>
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nazwa)
  </span>
  <span style='text-align: right; position:absolute; 
  bottom:0; right:0; font-size:25px;'>
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cena)
  </span>
  </div>
">
<img src="@item.FotoUrl" alt="@item.Nazwa" class="img-thumbnail" style="width:150px;height:auto;box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888888;"/>
</a>
</td>
```

It's look like:  [image]

I wanna add link into tooltip, so it should not dissapear on mouse over tooltip.

Any idea how can i do it?

Its not commercial project, I made it for passing a project school(its part of my online shop).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the attribute `data-html="true"`

So:

```
data-toggle="tooltip"
data-html="true"
```

Comment: What is it gonna change? My tooltip use html but it disappear after mouse over on (when i move mouse over the tooltip).

Answer (score 2):

Ok i find solution of my problem but i use popover instead of tooltip.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
   $("a.apop").popover({
    animation: false,
    placement: 'right',
    html: true,
    delay: { show: 750, hide: 100 },
    container: $(this).attr('id'),
    content: function () {
    $return = '<div class="hover-hovercard"></div>';
    }
    }).on("mouseenter", function () {
      var _this = this;
      $(this).popover("show");
      $(this).siblings(".popover").on("mouseleave", function () {
      $(_this).popover('hide');
    });
    }).on("mouseleave", function () {
      var _this = this;
      setTimeout(function () {
      if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
      $(_this).popover("hide")
      }
    }, 100);
  });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a tooltip where the trigger is manual and close it if the mous e is not hover the target element or the tooltip.

Excerpt of the example found on this [page](https://datacadamia.com/web/ui/bootstrap/tooltip#tooltip_that_is_not_closing_immediately_when_the_mouse_is_hovering_over_it) on a `mouseleave` event.

- the tooltip with a manual trigger

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-trigger="manual" data-bs-html="true" title="<h3>Tooltip</h3> <p>This tooltip will not close if you hover over the button or this tooltip</p>">
Button with a tooltip persistent on tooltip hover
</button>
```

- the javascript

```js
// A variable to see if the mouse is over the target element
let hoverTargetElement = false;
// The jobId that is returned from the setIntervall
let jobId = null;
$(`[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]`)
    .tooltip()
    .on("mouseenter", function () {
        $(this).tooltip("show");
        hoverTargetElement = true;
    })
    .on("mouseleave", function () {
        // the mouse is no more hover the target element (ie the button)
        hoverTargetElement = false;
        // if the jobId is not null, there is a job running
        if (jobId == null) {
            // keep a pointer to the target element used in the job function
            let _this = this;
            // Create the job function that will run ever 100 ms.
            jobId = setInterval(function () {
                if ($(".tooltip:hover").length === 0 && hoverTargetElement === false) {
                    $(_this).tooltip("hide")
                    clearInterval(jobId);
                    jobId = null;
                }
            }, 100);
        }
    });
```